# Writing PHP file not working

Tags: php, fwrite

I'm trying to dynamically write PHP files using the fwrite() function and it just does not seem to be working.  The code is definitely in the string being written, but then when I open the file that was written it just isn't there!  My assumption is that the PHP compiler is, for whatever reason, reading the PHP tags in the string, executing what's between them, and then abandoning them.  Is this assumption accurate? What can I do to get around it?

The code looks something like this:

```
$code = "<?php echo \"This is a dynamically written file!\"; ?>";
$openFile = fopen("filename.php","w");
fwrite($openFile,$code);
fclose($openFile);
```

I have tried both single and double quotes around the 'code' variable.

**EDIT:** I tried single quotes, but then the single-quoted variable was mixing with a double-quoted variable and converting it.  I feel dumb.  Sorry for wasting everybody's time.

Comment: So... what is the problem ? Generated file is empty or not executing... ?

Comment: usually a bad idea to write a *.php file with php

Comment: Have you tried writing the content string without the opening and closing php tags?

Comment: Code works fine when I've tested it...

Comment: @Dagon thats not exactly true. I am using this to generate "cache" with "array" data, so I have them instantly in PHP and I can use array right the way

Comment: cars10: Yeah, this is at the top of a file with a bunch of HTML, and the HTML still writes.

Comment: @MartinPerry: File is empty.

Comment: @MartinPerry *usually*

Comment: Does `error_get_last()` return anything after `fopen`?

Comment: I feel dumb.  I was mixing single and double quoted strings, making them both double.  Sorry for wasting everyone's time.  Dagon: What can go wrong?

Comment: The code sample is fine. You're asking a bad question.

Comment: @user2597300 What is the exactly code that you want to write. Because I test it, and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following so PHP doesn't parse the content of your string (single quotes):

```
$code = '<?php echo "This is a dynamically written file!"; ?>';
$openFile = fopen("filename.php","w");
fwrite($openFile,$code);
fclose($openFile);
```

Comment: I was not the one who downvoted you, for the record.  You were right, while I did say I tried that it was a situational problem and I didn't give enough detail.  I was then mixing the single quoted string with a double quoted string.

Answer (score 0):

`$code = "<"."?php echo \"This is a dynamically written file!\"; ?".">";`

PHP-tags are parsed.

Comment: They are not...I generate files with them without problem

Comment: As I said in a comment on the question... Code works flawlessly!

Answer (score 0):

You are likely having permission issues.  I got this to work.  To check use:

```
<?php

$code = "<?php echo \"This is a dynamically written file!\"; ?>";
$openFile = fopen("filename.php","w");

print_r(error_get_last());

fwrite($openFile,$code);
fclose($openFile);

?>
```

Does `print_r` yeild anything?

Comment: I agree with you. He maybe have a problem with permissions, because at me it works.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, turned out I need to use absolute path,
refer to [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45858233/2685783)

Answer (score 0):

You need to put litteral quotes around the string. You dont want PHP to parse it, you want litterly that string. Also, there is another function for that, [`file_put_contents()`](http://php.net/file_put_contents):

```
$code = '<?php echo "This is a dynamically written file!"; ?>';
$openFile = file_put_contents("filename.php");
```

> This function is identical to calling fopen(), fwrite() and fclose() successively to write data to a file.

**Be ware**: You're playing a dangerous game, writing other PHP files. You better be 110% sure what you're doing and double/triple check every step you take. Whatever it is you're doing, there is a safer way.